# PubNub on worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps, pubnub

**TL;DR see below**

A core feature of my android application is to broadcast the user's current location in a foreground service that continues to run after being unbound from the activity. I have everything working fine in terms of publishing to a channel and subscribers receiving the data from the channel. The service is working great. I'm even animating a google maps camera to follow the location received from the subscribed message.

My concern is that I'm getting this message:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I have of course researched this message. A lot of people seem to say it has something to do with animation, so I assume it has something to do with the map since it is the only thing animating. Though, I've also learned that the choreographer can produce this message because of other reasons.

When my application starts up, it launches a foreground service which connects to google location services using the GoogleAPIClient. After initialization, I immediately request my current location and use PubNub to broadcast the lng and lat to a channel. I then subcribe to that channel and when the message is received my MapFragmentPresenter class listens to location updates from the service. The presenter then calls the MapFragment's View (The V in MVP) to animate the camera and position the marker on each new location.

This is all working fine. I just want to make sure I'm not causing skipped frames and not putting too much work on the main thread. I'm doing very little on the main thread right now considering all the other stuff I have planned on doing on it. Right now I'm just continually repositioning the camera to follow the device's current location, pretty basic I would think.

Also, I am not using any wakelock features, yet my PubNub broadcasts are working fine. Why is this? I read somewhere that using PubNub running while the device is locked requires this, but mine is working without it.

Sorry for the long post.

**Note: I do not have large resource files. I haven't even really added anything other than icons I import from AS itself.**

**TL;DR** 
I seem to be doing too much on my main thread. Can google location services and PubNub operations be done on different threads in a service and will this fix my problem?

**Questions:**

1. Should/Can I do all of the location requests on a worker thread?
2. Should/Can PubNub operations be on their own thread?
3. Is anything I'm doing bad?
4. My foreground service seems to be working perfectly fine while the device is asleep/locked, but I have NOT messed with WAKE_LOCK at all. Should I? What's the difference in manipulating state of lock when my service seems to be doing everything I expect?

**Here's some of the code:**

**Thanks for taking the time!**

**MapViewFragment**

```
public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment
        implements OnMapReadyCallback, IMapFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MAP_VIEW_FRAGMENT";

    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap gMap;
    private IMapPresenter presenter;
    private boolean mapReady;
    private Handler handler;
    private LatLng myLocation;


    //ToDo: newInstance method

    //==========================
    //Fragment Lifecycle
    //==========================
    @Override @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mapReady = false;
        presenter = new MapPresenter(this);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_view, container, false);
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        return  v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }


    public MapPresenter getPresenter(){
        return (MapPresenter) presenter;
    }


    //==========================
    //Map
    //==========================
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        this.gMap = googleMap;
        mapReady = true;

    }


    @Override
    public void moveToMyLocation(final LatLng locData) {

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locData).title("myLocation"));
                gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locData,20));
                Log.d(TAG,"//////////////////moveToMyLocation");

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**Service**

```
public class MapService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MAP_VIEW_SERVICE";

    private int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 102;

    private LocationRequest gLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient gApiClient;

    private Pubnub mPubnub;

    private Location lastLocation;
    private String mapFragTag;

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private LatLng mLatLng;

    private ServiceRequestListener requestListener;

    //==========================
    //Service Lifecycle
    //==========================
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        gLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        gLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        gLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        gLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        gApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mPubnub = new Pubnub(
                getString(R.string.pubnub_publish_key)
                ,getString(R.string.pubnub_subscribe_key));

        try{
            mPubnub.subscribe("Channel-d2160eqlk",subscribeCallback);
        }catch (PubnubException e) {
            Log.e("**MapService**", e.toString());
        }

        gApiClient.connect();
        setupAndLaunchForeground();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            return START_STICKY;
}

    @Nullable @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(gApiClient.isConnected()) {
            gApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    public void setRequestListener(ServiceRequestListener requestListener) {
        this.requestListener = requestListener;
    }


    //==========================
    //StartForeground
    //==========================
    private void setupAndLaunchForeground() {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Service Running")
                .setTicker("AppName Services Initiated")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setOngoing(true);

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MapViewFragment.class);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                REQUEST_CODE, startIntent, 0);

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);

    }


    //==========================
    //Google API Client
    //==========================
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        if(manager.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,"com.firsttread.appname")
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(gApiClient, gLocationRequest, this);
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(gApiClient);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    //==========================
    //Location
    //==========================
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        broadcastLocation(location);
        this.lastLocation = location;

        Log.d("****LocationChange****","Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + "Lng: " + location.getLongitude());

    }


    //==========================
    //PubNub
    //==========================
    private void broadcastLocation(Location location){

        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

        try{
            message.put("lat", location.getLatitude());
            message.put("lng", location.getLongitude());
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("MapService", e.toString());
        }

        mPubnub.publish("ChannelName", message, publishCallback);

    }

    Callback publishCallback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
            Log.d("**PUBNUB**", response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
            Log.e("**PUBNUB**", error.toString());
        }
    };

    Callback subscribeCallback = new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {

            JSONObject jsonMessage = (JSONObject) message;
            try {
                double mLat = jsonMessage.getDouble("lat");
                double mLng = jsonMessage.getDouble("lng");

                if(requestListener != null){
                    sendLocation(new LatLng(mLat,mLng));
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("**PUBNUB_ERROR**", e.toString());
            }

        }
    };


    //==========================
    //Location Data Methods
    //==========================
    private void sendLocation(LatLng locData){
        requestListener.retrieveLocation(locData);
    }


    //==========================
    //MapInterface
    //==========================
    public interface ServiceRequestListener {
        void retrieveAppNameLocations(HashMap<String,Long> memberLocations);
        void retrieveLocation(LatLng locData);
    }

    //==========================
    //ServiceBinder
    //==========================
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MapService getService() {
            return MapService.this;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some answers to your questions:

**1. Should/Can I do all of the location requests on a worker thread?**
You shouldn't need to do anything special other than just subscribe to the channel that will have the location data published to it.

**2. Should/Can PubNub operations be on their own thread?**
They will be, just use the async APIs, not the sync APIs (you can't use sync in Android anyways without extra work, otherwise Android will throw exception).

**3. Is anything I'm doing bad? My foreground service seems to be working perfectly fine while the device is asleep/locked, but I have NOT messed with WAKE_LOCK at all. Should I?** 
At the time you asked this question, you might have been able config the WAKE_LOCK but might not be permitted anymore in lates Android OS (without additional permissions from end user, perhaps) but shouldn't matter. Just use push notifications when app is in background.

**4. What's the difference in manipulating state of lock when my service seems to be doing everything I expect?**
Not really sure what you mean here so would need more details.

If you are still having issues with the above, please [submit full details to PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com). Send sample project zipped (if possible), your PubNub sub-key and [PubNub SDK logs that captures any scenarios](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-android-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) you are having issues with.